# Drag drop error : Cannot access adorners on element that has no adorners

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, adorner

I am implementing the Drag drop solution mentioned here :

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53

I have few `ListBox`es + with `WrapPanel` and Items. i should be able to drag and drop item from any of the boxes to any other.

When I drag an item and move it across to another box, it throws me error:

Cannot access adorners on element that has no adorners.

at this line :

```
if (this.adornerLayer != null)
{
    this.adornerLayer.Update(this.AdornedElement);
}
```

I tried to see the value of AdornedElement i saw that it has this value :

`ListBoxItem : DisconnectedItem`. I saw the Content of `ListBoxItem` and seems it also has disconnected item.

The issue also happens if i move my items withing the same listbox. My listbox uses a wrapPanel as `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

the hierarch tree is like this of teh listBoxes are :

1 List box :
UserControl 
Border
Grid
Grid
Border
Border
Border
ScrollViewer
ListBox
ItemsPanel

Other 3 ListBoxes :
UserControl 
Border
Grid
Grid
Grid
tabControl
tabItem
Grid
Border
Border
Border
ScrollViewer
ListBox
ItemsPanel

AnyOne who has faced this issue or can help me what is going wrong ?

- Girija

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce this issue as well. I was able to prevent the error stop by changing the line of code to this:

```
if (this.adornerLayer != null && this.contentPresenter.Content != null)
{
    this.adornerLayer.Update(this.AdornedElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a .Net 4.0 bug

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e6643abc-4457-44aa-a3ee-dd389c88bd86?prof=required

you may also see this in tab controls.

Any time something is not displayed really, once your fall out of the visual tree your bindings can get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Tried approach jhamm suggested, unfortunately, it does not work for my case. I ended up modifying code that was suggested in thread on microsoft forum, mentioned above :

```
        ContentControl contentCtl = this.AdornedElement as ContentControl;
        if (contentCtl == null ||
            contentCtl.Content == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var contentType = contentCtl.Content.GetType();
        if (contentType.FullName.Equals("MS.Internal.NamedObject"))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.adornerLayer != null &&
            this.contentPresenter.Content != null)
        {
            try
            {
                this.adornerLayer.Update(this.AdornedElement);
            }
```

The check

```
        var contentType = contentCtl.Content.GetType();
        if (contentType.FullName.Equals("MS.Internal.NamedObject"))
        {
            return;
        }
```

fails when the item is disconnected.

By the way the bug reported to be fixed in 4.5

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me to check if the adornerlayer for the UIElement could be found before calling Update().

```
if (AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(uIElement) != null)
{
    this.adornerLayer.Update(uIElement);
}
```